# In Rails, do you need to be careful of creating too many modles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

I'm creating a customized "Buy Now" page that is a combination of User, address, Sale, SaleLine, and Payment models.  To initiate the payment process, I need to specifie the Sale ID in a callback.  So my #new method looks something like this...

```
# new
def bitcoin
  require 'cgi'
  @payment_to_tender = get_cost

  @sale = Sale.create

  begin
    payment = create_new_payment_wallet(ENV["BITCOIN"], "http://www.example.com/a/b", @sale.id)
  end
end
```

So the key line in there is the middle where a new Sale record is created.  This page doesn't require any kind of login or anything (because it's the signup page technically).  Will this be a problem?  I think anytime, even a bot navigates to the page, it will spawn yet another Sale record.  Will that eventually catch up with me?  Should I run a script nightly that deletes all orphan Sale records that are older than a day, or should I try a different algo?

Comment: I'd first question how Sale.create is even valid. But aside from that, no, you should generally not create models via a GET request. Use POST: `post '/bitcoin' => 'controller#action'`. You would have two actions. One for initializing the form, and one for managing the form request (usually a POST).

Comment: Sale.create is just for setting it's id, there aren't any validations on that model, most of the fields in it are just calculations based on SaleLines so I don't expect to run into any problems with validity there.  I'm thinking I might stetch out the process to two views now, the first a form for creating the User and purchasing details, and the second simply displaying the temporary bitcoin address they need to send money to before shipping can happen.  Maybe after some refactoring down the road I can get this more conventional...

Comment: That's a problem. You're creating a Sale before a successful transaction has gone through, before even a form has been submitted. You're right, that will lead to a bloated table full of worthless data. Create a Sale when a transaction has been processed.

Answer (score 1):

**Rails can handle as many models as required**

Models are just `.rb` files which are opened when you call ActiveRecord, they're not applications or anything super-resource intensive

However, what they represent is much more than just opening a file. The question you're *really* asking is "is my schema set up correctly?", which is a different ballgame

---

**ActiveRecord Assocations**

Rails is "[object orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)", which means *everything* you do has to work around an object. This is typically an `ActiveRecord Object`, which is made up of a database query & associated data

One of the biggest problems with Rails apps is an inefficient use of the ActiveRecord Association structure. [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) work by defining "relations" in your models, allowing you to call one piece of data & automatically have its related data attached in the object

The problem for most people is ActiveRecord Assocations pick up data they don't need, causing unnecessary expensive database calls. This is where the problems arise, and is what you're trying to address

---

**Creating Independent Records**

If you want to create a record with another, you can use the `after_create` method, like this:

```
#app/models/bitcoin.rb
Class BitCoin < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_create :create_sale
end
```

This will actually create a sale record for you, if it's related correctly